# Как сделать так, чтобы аннотации, отображаемые на объектах на карте, увеличивались в размере при нажатии

Tags: mapbox

Пожалуйста, помогите нам решить следующую проблему. Как сделать так, чтобы аннотации, отображаемые на объектах на карте, увеличивались в размере при нажатии.
Все работает, если у нас есть один и тот же тип маркеров, но, например, если я беру 5 маркеров и рисую разные маркеры при каждом щелчке, тогда маркеры не меняются и раскрашивают маркеры друг друга (увеличение обычно увеличивается)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didDeselect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {
    self.currentAnnotation = nil
    self.printPoiImage(with: imageName, annotation: annotation, mapView: mapView)
}
```

private func printPoiImage(with name: String, annotation: MGLAnnotation, mapView: MGLMapView) {
let id = "(annotation.coordinate.latitude)+(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"
let annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: id)
annotationImage?.image = UIImage(named: name)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didSelect annotation: MGLAnnotation) {

```
    if self.currentAnnotation == nil {
        self.currentAnnotation = annotation
        self.printPoiImage(with: imageName+"b", annotation: annotation, mapView: mapView)
    }
}
```

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
let id = "(annotation.coordinate.latitude)+(annotation.coordinate.longitude)"
var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: id)

```
    var image: UIImage?
    if self.currentAnnotation == nil {
        image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    } else {
        image = UIImage(named: imageName+"b")
    }
    guard var imageWrap = image else { return nil }
    imageWrap = imageWrap.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: imageWrap.size.height/2, right: 0))
    annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: imageWrap, reuseIdentifier: id)
    return annotationImage
}
```

var mapView: NavigationMapView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
    mapView = NavigationMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)
    mapView!.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    mapView!.delegate = self
    mapView!.userTrackingMode = .follow
    mapView!.compassViewMargins = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 55)
    mapView?.navigationMapViewDelegate = self
}
```

Comment: может кто то помочь в этом вопросе?

Comment: Кто-нибудь может мне помочь?

Comment: может кто то помочь в этом вопросе?

Comment: В вашем вопросе слишком мало информации для ответа. Например, не ясно на какой платформе вам это надо. Мобильное приложение (андроид, иос, кросплатформа (и какая из множества)), сайт, что-то ещё. Также не ясно как вы карту интегрируете - их SDK, встроенный браузер или что-то ещё. Ну и не ясно что вы сами пытались для решения задачи сделать - возможно в доке есть даже пример того, как вашу проблему решить, который вы даже пробовали, но у вас что-то не вышло. Коли так - расскажите подробно об этом. Многие могут помочь, но вот выпытывать все эти детали у многих просто нет времени.